# Imported and reexported not found in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli, bootstrap-vue

I am following a tutorial on YouTube about Vue, everything was working fine until I installed Bootstrap Vue and I ran `npm run serve`, I keep getting this error:

```sh
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 WARNING  Compiled with 2 warnings                                                                                          2:21:24 AM
 warning  in ./src/main.js

"export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'

 warning  in ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/vue.js

"export 'default' (reexported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using version 2 and not version 3?

Comment: I checked the version and I saw vue/cli 4.5.1 ... Is that a problem? Can I downgrade it?

Comment: You can create a Vue 2 or 3 project with that version. Can you check the version for Vue in your `package.json`?

Comment: Or just include your `package.json` in the question?

Comment: Can you include `main.js` in your question also?

Comment: The version is 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

BootstrapVue isn't compatible with Vue 3 yet:

> BootstrapVue provides one of the most comprehensive implementations of the Bootstrap v4.5 component and grid system available for **Vue.js v2.6**

You'll either have to use Vue 2, use Vue 3 *without* Bootstrap or find another component library which *is* compatible with Vue 3.